# Let $z=a e^t$ then $dz=ae^tdt$, How to define $d \overline{z}=?$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, complex-manifolds

Let $z$ and $t$ be two complex variables such that $z=a e^t$ where $a$ is a (real or complex) constant. Thus, the differential form $dz$ is nothing but $ae^tdt$, i.e., $$dz=ae^tdt.$$ The question is:

How to define the differential form $d \overline{z}$? $$d \overline{z}=?$$

Comment: It should be $d \overline z = \overline a e^{\overline t} \overline {dt}$. The $\overline {dt}$ is the problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni could you please explain it to me please?

Comment: I assumed you wanted to express $d \overline z$ in terms of $dt$. The first step $d \overline z = \overline a e^{\overline t} \overline {dt}$ is only the application of conjugation. Then the trouble is: how to express $\overline {dt}$ in terms of $dt$? It appears this is impossible: conjugation is not $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable, although it is $\mathbb{R}^2$-differentiable (which is weaker). Cf. for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Examples

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni don't you think we have $\overline{dt}= d \overline{t}$?

Comment: Yes, $\overline{dt}= d \overline{t}$. But that's still not $dt$ alone. So it depends upon your needs; usually we want differential elements such as $dt$ to appear as a factor only. For example here you cannot get an expression for $\frac {\overline {dz}} {dt} =$ from that.